# ошибка в IDE Anjuta: отсутствуют automake и libtool

Tags: debian, ide

Debian GNU/Linux jessie.

Все библиотеки и *multilib* поставлены для *g++ gcc*

*automake* *libtool* тоже поставлены - пишет в установщике пакетов/приложений.

При попытке компиляции в *Anjuta* кода *C++* пишет данные ошибки:

> **Error**: You must have `libtool' installed. You can get it from: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/
>
> **Error**: You must have `automake' installed. You can get it from: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/

UPD по поводу версий. опять же в установщике пакетов/приложений пишет что библиотека установлена и все «сопутствующие товары» тоже.

```
$ automake --version
bash: automake: команда не найдена
$ libtool --version
bash: libtool: команда не найдена
```

UPD

```
# aptitude -f install libtool   
# aptitude -f install automake 
Ни одного
пакета не будет установлено, обновлено или удалено. 0 пакетов
обновлено, 0 установлено новых, 0 пакетов отмечено для удаления, и 2
пакетов не обновлено. Необходимо получить 0 B архивов. После
распаковки 0 B будет занято.
```

UPD

```
# dpkg -L libtool automake |grep bin 
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/libtoolize 
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/automake-1.14
/usr/bin/aclocal-1.14
```

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте к вопросу вывод двух команд: `libtool --version` и `automake --version`. внести изменения в вопрос можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: @alexanderbarakin добавил в вопрос. на linux mint и linux ubuntu на которых сидел/сижу(на ноутбуке) такого небыло. qt работает нормально

Comment: попробуйте установить пакеты: `sudo aptitude -f install automake libtool`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin обновил

Comment: к сожалению, вы так отформатировали строки, что совершенно непонятно, что за команду(-ы) вы выполняли. добавьте ещё, пожалуйста, вывод команды `dpkg -L libtool automake | grep bin`. как пользоваться форматированием, написано в [справке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin прописал

Comment: вероятно, мэйнтэйнеры что-то «поломали». судя по ранее приведённому выводу `aptitude install`, у вас два пакета ждут обновления. попробуйте, всё-таки обновить (сначала список, а затем и пакеты): `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude safe-upgrade`. вполне возможно, что это как раз исправления в этих пакетах.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin 39мб чего то скачал и обновил [-2], не работает все равно

Comment: ага! сейчас программу `libtool` вынесли в пакет `libtool-bin`. установите этот пакет. а для появления программы (точнее, symlink-а) `automake` выполните: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure automake`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в *jessie*, который, судя по всему, у вас установлен, программу `/usr/bin/libtool` вынесли в пакет `libtool-bin`, который и надо установить:

```
$ sudo aptitude install libtool-bin
```

а для восстановления (почему-то отсутствующего) *symlink*-а `/usr/bin/automake` можно выполнить такую команду:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure automake
```